# How can I change the session expiry of session entries in the Cookie Jar?

Tags: paw-app

Within the Paw App, I consider the Cookie Jar as a template for common session scenarios. Set up "n" number of sessions, set their domain and name, and save for future use. The session values need to be updated, no way around that.

However, when creating a Cookie Jar, how do you set the expiry date? The date seems to be auto-filled for a few hours in the future (mind you the date seems to be wrong anyway - see screenshot, noting the year 4001 and the day being 2 days prior to present).

Ideally I would like to set it to say "+2 weeks" - because the alternative it completely clearing out the Cookie Jar every few hours to create new dates, which means re-creating the name, domain and value attributes everytime.

[image]

EDIT: Ignore the year 4001, it appears to update after saving and moving away from the modal. The original question stands about updating expiry dates

EDIT EDIT: The 4001 is still appearing

EDIT EDIT EDIT

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening with the date, but seeing the `Set-Cookie` header returned by the server would greatly help debug this. Any chance of having this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Micha - Thanks I have attached an image (and sent an email)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I got it, we will debug this closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current state of the Paw app (2016-01-30) this can't be done. However the team are actively working on the app, so I will update this answer in the future